# Does this norm inequality hold?

Tags: analysis, inequality, normed-spaces, absolute-value

Does this inequality hold?

> Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Is it true that
> $$ \left\lvert \frac{\lVert x \rVert}{\sqrt n \sqrt 3}-\frac{1}{3} \right\rvert \leq  \displaystyle\left\lvert  \frac{\lVert x \rVert ^2}{n}-\frac{1}{3} \right\rvert .$$

Here $\lVert \cdot \rVert$ denotes 2-norm in $\mathbb R ^n$ and $\lvert \cdot \rvert$ the absolute value in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Hint: the RHS is the LHS times $\sqrt{3}(u+1/\sqrt{3})$ where $u+\|x\|/\sqrt{n}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$\left| \frac{||x||^2}{n} - \frac{1}{3}\right| = \left| \frac{||x||}{\sqrt n} - \frac{1}{\sqrt 3}\right| \cdot \left| \frac{||x||}{\sqrt n} + \frac{1}{\sqrt 3}\right|$$
while
$$\left| \frac{||x||}{\sqrt 3 \sqrt n} - \frac{1}{3}\right| = \frac{1}{\sqrt 3}\left| \frac{||x||}{\sqrt n} - \frac{1}{\sqrt 3}\right| $$
Thus your inequality is equivalent to
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt 3} \le \left| \frac{||x||}{\sqrt n} + \frac{1}{\sqrt 3}\right| \ \ \mbox{ or } \ \  \left| \frac{||x||}{\sqrt n} - \frac{1}{\sqrt 3}\right|=0$$
which can be rewritten as
$$0 \le ||x||  \ \ \mbox{ or } \ \  ||x|| = \sqrt{\frac{n}{3}}$$
which is clearly true.